# Lambdas and Streams (Array)

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

A bit weak with the concept of lambdas and streams so there might be stuff that really doesn't make any sense but I'll try to convey what I want to happen.

I have a class Invoice where there is an item name, price, and quantity.
I'm having to map the item name and to the total cost (price*quantity).

Though it doesn't work, hope it gives an idea what problem I am having:

```
invoiceList.stream()
           .map(Invoice::getDesc)
           .forEach(System.out.println(Invoice::getPrice*Invoice::getQty));
```

I can already tell the forEach would not work as it's mapping to a variable description(getDesc) and not the Invoice object where I can use it's methods to get other variables.

So, if `item=pencil, price=1, qty=12`, the output I would want is:

```
Pencil   12.00
```

This would be done on multiple Invoice objects.

Also, I am needing to sort them by their total and also filter those above a certain amount, eg. 100. How am I supposed to do that after having them placed in Map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if all you want to do is print to the console then it can be done as follows:

```
invoiceList.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i.getName() + "    " + (i.getPrice() * i.getQty())));
```

If not then read on:

## Using the toMap collector

```
Map<String, Double> result = 
     invoiceList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Invoice::getName, 
                                  e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity()));
```

This basically creates a map where the keys are the `Invoice` names and the values are the multiplication of the invoice price and quantity for that given `Invoice`.

## Using the groupingBy collector


However, if there can be multiple invoices with the same name then you can use the `groupingBy` collector along with `summingDouble` as the downstream collector:

```
Map<String, Double> result = 
     invoiceList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(Invoice::getName, 
                  Collectors.summingDouble(e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity())));
```

This groups the `Invoice`'s by their names and then for each group sums the result of `e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity()`.

---

**Update:**

if you want the `toMap` version and the result filtered then sorted by value ascending it can be done as follows:

```
Map<String, Double> result = invoiceList.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity() > 100)
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Invoice::getName,
                    e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity(), 
                    (left, right) -> left,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
```

or with `groupingBy` approach :

```
 Map<String, Double> result =
                invoiceList.stream()
                        .collect(groupingBy(Invoice::getName,
                                Collectors.summingDouble(e -> e.getPrice() * e.getQuantity())))
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 100)
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Map.Entry::getValue, (left, right) -> left,
                                LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: This works great but how do I then sort according to variable e? Maybe from lowest total to highest. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much, but may I ask what exactly would be the difference between both methods? Just a different approach?

Comment: @CarameliaBachmann no, it's not just a different approach. as mentioned in my answer, if the invoice name is unique in your design model then use the `toMap` but if there can be multiple invoice objects with the same name then you need to use `groupingBy`.

Answer (score 1):

So first, here's the code that I think you were trying to write:

```java
invoiceList.stream()
       .forEach(invoice -> System.out.println(invoice.getPrice() * invoice.getQty()));
```

Now let's look at what's going on here:

Calling `.stream()` on your list creates an object that has methods available for doing operations on the contents of the list. `foreach` is one such method that invokes a function on each element. `map` is another such method, but it returns another stream, where the contents are the contents of your original stream, but each element is replaced by the return value of the function that you pass to map.

If you look at the inside of the foreach call, you can see a lambda. This defines an anonymous function that will be called on each element of your `invoiceList`. The `invoice` variable to the left of the `->` symbol is bound to each element of the stream, and the expression to the right executed.